# Manual routing & SNAT doesn't work with Openvpn

Tags: proxy, openvpn, ip-forwarding

I cannot figure out which configurations went wrong so that manual routing with OpenVPN cannot work.

Here is the general idea to hide the Client's public IP under the Server's:

**[App -> tun0(10.0.0.2) -> Openvpn Client] ----> [Openvpn Server(10.0.0.1) -> eth0->Public IP]---->[Any Site on www]**

What is absolutely certain now is that until Openvpn Server(10.0.0.1) everything is normal.

I can track the communications in the Openvpn tunnel either on the Client or on the Server, by tcpdump or by its own log above verb 7.

In the test, I use `curl` as the APP on Client, simple `curl --interface tun0 google.com` will start the chain.

**Server Config**

```
dev tun0
lport 1100
proto udp
ifconfig 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2
secret static 0
tun-mtu 1400
txqueuelen 1000
fragment 0
mssfix 0
log-append /var/some.log
verb 7
```

In addition, SNAT settings of ip_forward and masquerade are On:

```
# cd /proc/sys/net/ipv4
# cat ip_forward
1
# firewall-cmd --info-zone=public
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 1100/udp 1200/udp 1200/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

**Client Config**

```
daemon
dev tun
remote [openvpn server's IP]
rport 1100
lport 1100
proto udp
ifconfig 10.0.0.2 10.0.0.1
secret static 1
writepid /run/tunpid
log-append /var/some.log
tun-mtu 1400
txqueuelen 1000
fragment 0
mssfix 0
verb 7
```

In addition, any traffic through tun0 is manually routed through the peer Openvpn server:

```
# ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 table vpn
# ip route list table vpn
default via 10.0.0.1 dev tun0
```

Other than "def1" routing, which means any traffic to other hosts is routed through the vpn peer 10.0.0.1, this configuration means any traffic from tun0  is routed through the vpn peer.

**Log on Server** as the client executed `curl --interface tun0 google.com`

```
Sun Jun  5 06:52:37 2022 us=280095 UDPv4 READ [100] from [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:37 2022 us=280157 PID_TEST [0] [STATIC-0] [EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE] 1654411282:24 1654411282:25 t=1654411957[0] r=[0,64,15,0,1] sl=[40,24,64,528]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:37 2022 us=280176 TUN WRITE [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:37 2022 us=280782 TUN READ [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:37 2022 us=280803 UDPv4 WRITE [100] to [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:37 2022 us=584143 TUN READ [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:37 2022 us=584220 UDPv4 WRITE [100] to [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:38 2022 us=281407 UDPv4 READ [100] from [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:38 2022 us=281460 PID_TEST [0] [STATIC-0] [1EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE] 1654411282:25 1654411282:26 t=1654411958[0] r=[-1,64,15,0,1] sl=[39,25,64,528]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:38 2022 us=281471 TUN WRITE [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:38 2022 us=281984 TUN READ [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:38 2022 us=282006 UDPv4 WRITE [100] to [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:40 2022 us=287353 UDPv4 READ [100] from [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:40 2022 us=287413 PID_TEST [0] [STATIC-0] [23EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE] 1654411282:26 1654411282:27 t=1654411960[0] r=[-3,64,15,0,1] sl=[38,26,64,528]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:40 2022 us=287425 TUN WRITE [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:40 2022 us=287924 TUN READ [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:40 2022 us=287948 UDPv4 WRITE [100] to [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:42 2022 us=304171 TUN READ [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:42 2022 us=304246 UDPv4 WRITE [100] to [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:46 2022 us=336203 TUN READ [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:46 2022 us=336289 UDPv4 WRITE [100] to [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
Sun Jun  5 06:52:54 2022 us=400251 TUN READ [60]
Sun Jun  5 06:52:54 2022 us=400332 UDPv4 WRITE [100] to [AF_INET][Client VPN Port]:  DATA len=100
```

Any suggestion on solving the problem is appreciated.
But I do not need the suggestion to use default routing `def1`, since that setting won't address the need that Client's traffic shall not get routed through openvpn unless specified using tun0.

---

`conntrack -E` tracks the client did ask the server, and the server tried to connect google.com 142.250.74.174:80 but it does not change the source IP instead it just wrote 10.0.0.2 so google.com cannot reply it. Simply put, there is no masquerading on the server.

```
   [NEW] udp      17 30 src=[Client's IP] dst=[Server's IP] sport=1100 dport=1100 [UNREPLIED] src=[Server's IP] dst=[Client's IP] sport=1100 dport=1100
    [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=10.0.0.2 dst=142.250.74.174 sport=60418 dport=80 [UNREPLIED] src=142.250.74.174 dst=[Server's IP] sport=80 dport=60418
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=10.0.0.2 dst=142.250.74.174 sport=60418 dport=80 src=142.250.74.174 dst=[Server's IP] sport=80 dport=60418
 [UPDATE] udp      17 30 src=[Client's IP] dst=[Server's IP] sport=1100 dport=1100 src=[Server's IP] dst=[Client's IP] sport=1100 dport=1100
 [UPDATE] udp      17 180 src=[Client's IP] dst=[Server's IP] sport=1100 dport=1100 src=[Server's IP] dst=[Client's IP] sport=1100 dport=1100 [ASSURED]
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 59 SYN_RECV src=10.0.0.2 dst=142.250.74.174 sport=60418 dport=80 src=142.250.74.174 dst=[Server's IP] sport=80 dport=60418
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=10.0.0.2 dst=142.250.74.174 sport=60418 dport=80 src=142.250.74.174 dst=[Server's IP] sport=80 dport=60418
 [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=10.0.0.2 dst=142.250.74.174 sport=60418 dport=80 src=142.250.74.174 dst=[Server's IP] sport=80 dport=60418
```

Comment: Have you made sure there is a route back as well? Can you follow the flow with tcpdump?

Comment: Does it work if you `push redirect-gateway def1` from the server ?

Comment: masquerade is on, but did you verify it actually works? You could use tcpdump on eth0 or on Linux use `conntrack -E` to check this. Generally, you should validate that settings at a higher level (openvpn config) are applied as expected at the basic network level (route etc.).

Comment: I don't see any `ip rule` referencing  `table vpn`. Or is that part of the configuration done by openvpn too?

Comment: @NiKiZe On theory there should be this routing back. Because `ip_forward=1` shall have made the server as a "switcher", or "router", communicating between at least two subnets. a machine on subnet 10.0.0.0/30, i.e. 10.0.0.2 asks it to route, so it sends the request on google.com by its public IP or eth0 IP, and as the reply comes to this IP, it sends the reply back to 10.0.0.2. This is called "Source Net Address Transfer".

Comment: @A.B. the `ip rule` referencing `table vpn` is shown by the command line`# ip route list table vpn` - it did reference table vpn, but only on the client machine. There are traffic back and forth between 10.0.0.2 and 10.0.0.1 as you can see from the log by "from" and "to"'s. I would check it using your method later.  This is very strange, though, that it worked for months, but suddenly failed on June 1st.

Comment: alternate tables isn't the same thing as ip rule. Without an ip rule that looks up the table(s) the routes in it simply won't be used. (There's also VRF though.)

Comment: As Tom Yan wrote, if there's no `ip rule show` output showing a reference to a routing table shown with for example `ip route show table vpn` then this routing table is not used: useless. It's surprising you don't know about ip rule. Read documentation for example there (it's old but still mostly relevant): http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.6 or there: https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html or ...

Comment: @TomYan @A.B. upon your request, the `ip rule show` gets `0:  from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main  32767:  from all lookup default`

Comment: @TomYan @A.B. There is no masquerading on the server as I just checked the connections by `conntrack -E` from A.B.

Comment: you need a valid route in both directions, `ip_forward=1` does not automatically add that, you need routes to know where the packets should go (there is also route protection that drops packages coming in on an interface without a valid route back out that interface)

Comment: Interesting. Looks like at least for `tun` with `--interface` in `curl` you don't need *any* (default?) route added to *any* route table, which means `table vpn` here is a *red herring*. I am not familiar with firewalld, but maybe the fact that the zone (`public`) your are listing has nothing in `interfaces:` or `sources:` *might* be relevant. You might want to add `iptables-save` (or perhaps `nft list ruleset`, no sure if firewalld could be using nftables as its backend) dump to your question.

Comment: @NiKiZe the existing default route on the server will be used for forwarded traffics as well, unless specified otherwise by some means, and the server config *should* (better check though) cause route for the client's VPN address to be added as well.